# how to pass js variable as key into options array

Tags: php, javascript, swfupload

I'm trying to use a variable as the "key" value in a javascript swfupload object's options array. The receiving page to an ajax request checks the session name/id before continuing processing, so these values are required.

However, since the session name is variable, I can't just set it statically. I'm trying something like this:

```
var myid        = ".$php_pageid.";
var sessionid   = '".$php_sessionid."'; 
var sessionname = '".$php_sessionname."';
var swfu = new SWFUpload({
    // Backend Settings
    upload_url: "index.php",
    post_params: 
    {
        "task" : "ajaxUpload",
        "id" : myid, 
        sessionname : sessionid 
    },
```

However, when I `console.dir` the swfu object, it shows

```
sessionname: "234630019cc86c366e1fa390ac737648"
```

instead of

```
d9fb7fb097782697802a63e5f65b765e: "234630019cc86c366e1fa390ac737648"
```

as is required.

I know I could simply do

```
var swfu = new SWFUpload({
    // Backend Settings
    upload_url: "index.php",
    post_params: 
    {
        "task" : "ajaxUpload",
        "id" : myid, 
        "'.$php_sessionname.'" : "'.$php_sessionid.'"
    },
```

But I'm abstracting the js into its own file, and setting all the vars in the PHP file.

Is there a proper way to set a variable as the key of an option pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it dynamically rather than declaratively:

```
var params = {
    "task" : "ajaxUpload",
    "id" : myid
};

params[sessionname] = sessionid;

var swfu = new SWFUpload({
    // Backend Settings
    upload_url: "index.php",
    post_params: params,
```

Comment: This might be seen as a security risk, though. Why expose the session name to JavaScript? Why not use a constant string?

Comment: Hi Matt-- can you elaborate on "use a constant string"? thanks

Comment: Use a constant key instead of the session name, e.g `{...sessionname: sessionid...}`. I'm curious to know why you're passing this at all. Seems like a pretty gaping security hole, or at least a code smell.